# Outlook style Listview in WPF Listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I am working on a system that manages documents and I currently implement a text search. The result shall be displayed in a list view similar to:

[image: Email list in Outlook]

Each hit shall be displayed in a combined row with some information where the tit was found and a short embedded preview. The columns shall be resizable and the text shall be aligned with the width of the columns.

I have seen some examples how this can be done in Windows Forms but not using WPF. Can anybody point me to an example how to create a list view with sch type of rows.

Greetings
   Clemens

Comment: What examples have you tried already? What is different about those?

Comment: They are for Windows Forms - not for WPF (like this one: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/705/Report-control-an-Outlook-style-SuperGrid-Rep)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I can do it with datagrid that I style for my needs.

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridExample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridExample"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Hit List" Height="350" Width="350">
<Window.Resources>
    <!-- Hover state brush -->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HoverBackgroundBrushKey" Color="#E5F3FB" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HoverBorderBrushKey" Color="#70C0E7" />

    <!-- Select (activate) the state of the brush -->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedActiveBackgroundBrushKey" Color="#CBE8F6" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedActiveBorderBrushKey" Color="#26A0DA" />

    <!-- Select (hover) state brush -->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedHoverBackgroundBrushKey" Color="#D1E8FF" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedHoverBorderBrushKey" Color="#66A7E8" />

    <!-- Select the (failed) status brush -->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedInactiveBackgroundBrushKey" Color="#F7F7F7" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedInactiveBorderBrushKey" Color="#DEDEDE" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="HitList" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              GridLinesVisibility="None"
              RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible"
              RowHeaderWidth="0"
              VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" 
              VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Hits}">
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                            <Border x:Name="BackgroundBorder" Background="Transparent">
                                <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,0,6,0" />
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>

        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background"  Value="{StaticResource HoverBackgroundBrushKey}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SelectedActiveBackgroundBrushKey}" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource SelectedActiveBackgroundBrushKey}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SelectedInactiveBackgroundBrushKey}" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Document" MinWidth="50" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DocumentName, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="0,0,12,0" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Field" MinWidth="50" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Field, Mode=OneWay}"  Margin="0,0,12,0" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Location" MinWidth="50" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Location, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="0,0,12,0" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Length" MinWidth="50" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Length, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="0,0,12,0" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderThickness="2,2,8,2"
                        Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsPresenter}}, Path=ActualWidth}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                    <TextBlock Margin="24,0,0,8" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <TextBlock.Inlines>
                            <Run Text="{Binding Path=MatchEnvironment.Head}" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="DarkGray"/>
                            <Run Text="{Binding Path=MatchEnvironment.Hit}" Background="Yellow" Foreground="Blue" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic"/>
                            <Run Text="{Binding Path=MatchEnvironment.Tail}" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="DarkGray"/>
                        </TextBlock.Inlines>
                    </TextBlock>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>

    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```